# Unity ECS/Burst on IOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I have created a new project using Unity 2019.3.0f6 under macOS Mojave.10.14.6

Added a simple cube to the scene and included the following packages from the Package Manager:

- Entities preview.11 - 0.5.1
- Burst 1.2.2

I can build the project fine on Unity as Release and it builds successfully on xCode(v11.3.1).

But when I try to run it on iPhone X device with IOS 13.3.1 I am getting the following exception:

> NotSupportedException: To marshal a managed method, please add an
>   attribute named 'MonoPInvokeCallback' to the method definition. The
>   method we're attempting to marshal is:
>   Unity.Entities.StructuralChange::AddComponentEntitiesBatchExecute at
>   Unity.Burst.BurstCompiler.Compile[T] (T delegateObj, System.Boolean
>   isFunctionPointer) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
>   at Unity.Entities.StructuralChange.Initialize () [0x00000] in
>   <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at
>   Unity.Entities.EntityManager..ctor (Unity.Entities.World world)
>   [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at
>   Unity.Entities.World..ctor (System.String name) [0x00000] in
>   <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at
>   Unity.Entities.DefaultWorldInitialization.Initialize (System.String
>   defaultWorldName, System.Boolean editorWorld) [0x00000] in
>   <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
>
> (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

Any idea why this is happening with a simple project?

Comment: Id ask on the unity ECS forums as dots is not production ready yet

Comment: You need to add [MonoPInvokeCallback] above your method

Comment: Do you have any update on this ? We are having the exact same issue.

Comment: Yes - I've resolved this issue by adding [AOT.MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof())] s into EntityManagerChangeArchetype.cs file for the managed methods.

Comment: Which methods did you put it on?

Comment: All the methods with [BurstCompile] attribute inside StructuralChange struct.